# AWS CodePipeline "The deployment failed because the AppSpec file that specifies the deployment configuration is missing ...."

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to set up a deployment pipeline using CodeCommit, ECR and ECS. My pipeline passes the source and builds the image right, except for deployment phase, where it fails:

**The deployment failed because the AppSpec file that specifies the deployment configuration is missing or has an invalid configuration. The input AppSpec file is a not well-formed yaml. The template cannot be parsed.**

appspec.yaml is in the output of my build phase (stored inside a zip file in S3)

The following is my code pipeline:

```js
{
    "pipeline": {
        "name": "dashboardpipeline",
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::410208438878:role/service-role/AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-us-east-2-DashBoardPipeline",
        "artifactStore": {
            "type": "S3",
            "location": "codepipeline-us-east-2-276644567431"
        },
        "stages": [
            {
                "name": "Source",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Source",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Source",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeCommit",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 2,
                        "configuration": {
                            "BranchName": "master",
                            "OutputArtifactFormat": "CODE_ZIP",
                            "PollForSourceChanges": "false",
                            "RepositoryName": "provisions_dashboard"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "inputArtifacts": [],
                        "region": "us-east-2",
                        "namespace": "SourceVariables"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Image",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Source",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "ECR",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 2,
                        "configuration": {
                            "ImageTag": "latest",
                            "RepositoryName": "dashboard-web-app"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "MyImage"
                            }
                        ],
                        "inputArtifacts": [],
                        "region": "us-east-2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Build",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Build",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Build",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeBuild",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "ProjectName": "DashboardApplicationBuild"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "region": "us-east-2",
                        "namespace": "BuildVariables"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Deploy",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Deploy",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Deploy",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeDeployToECS",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "AppSpecTemplateArtifact": "BuildArtifact",
                            "AppSpecTemplatePath": "appspec.yaml",
                            "ApplicationName": "dashboarddeploymentapp",
                            "DeploymentGroupName": "dashboardappdeploygr",
                            "Image1ArtifactName": "MyImage",
                            "Image1ContainerName": "IMAGE_URI",
                            "TaskDefinitionTemplateArtifact": "BuildArtifact",
                            "TaskDefinitionTemplatePath": "taskdef.json"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [],
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildArtifact"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "MyImage"
                            }
                        ],
                        "region": "us-east-2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "version": 18
    },
    "metadata": {
        "pipelineArn": "arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-2:410208438878:dashboardpipeline",
        "created": "2022-03-14T11:52:19.525000-03:00",
        "updated": "2022-03-18T11:34:14.217000-03:00"
    }
}
```